# Does c# short-circuit the &= and |= operator

Tags: c#, operators, short-circuiting

I know that the `&&` operator and `||` operators are short-circuited in c#.
But are the `&=` operators and `|=` operators as well?
Suppose I have a statement:

```
bool a = doSomething();
a &= doNext();
```

Is this guaranteed to be equivalent to:

```
bool a = doSomething();
if(!a)
  a = doNext();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that would actually be equivalent to:

```
a = a & doNext()
```

Google for bitwise operations to see more.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So it won't short-circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx and no it is not equal to &&. It is a short version of & operator plus assigment. doNext method would be called and executed for any "a" value.

Comment: So, by "Yes it does", you mean "No it does not short-circuit"?

Comment: I missunderstood your question a little. I thought short-circuit means &= instead of = ... & ... . Sorry